# Getting OAuth2 access token for Youtube API through Swift

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, youtube-data-api

I am working on an iOS mobile application where I need to upload videos using the Youtube Data API. In general, I understand the workflow needed:

1) Send a request to an authentication endpoint using clientId, clientSecret, and other details.

2) The service authenticates the client, and sends back a request to a client-specified callbackURL containing the access token.

3) The client provides the token in the header whenever he/she wants sends future requests.

I've successfully uploaded Youtube videos using node.js script, but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how to implement this in Swift. In my **VideoManagementController**, I have a button that triggers the upload of a **sample.mp4** file:

```
   let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(self.newToken))"]

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: ".mp4")


        let videodata : NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path!)! as! NSData
        print("TOKEN: \(String(describing: token))")
        Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=id", method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in

            print(response)
        }
```

I am attempting to retrieve my access token in the **viewDidLoad()** stage of the controller:

```
  let authorizationEndpoint = URL(string: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth")
    let tokenEndpoint = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")
    let configuration = OIDServiceConfiguration(authorizationEndpoint: authorizationEndpoint!, tokenEndpoint: tokenEndpoint!)

    let request = OIDAuthorizationRequest(configuration: configuration, clientId: self.kClientID, scopes: [OIDScopeOpenID, OIDScopeProfile], redirectURL: self.KRedirectURI!, responseType: OIDResponseTypeCode, additionalParameters: nil)

    let appDelegate: AppDelegate? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)
    print("REACHED")

    appDelegate?.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: self, callback: {(_ authState: OIDAuthState?, _ error: Error?) -> Void in
        if (authState != nil) {
            print("TOKEN: Got authorization tokens. Access token: \(String(describing: authState?.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken))")
            self.newToken = authState?.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken
            self.authState = authState
        }
        else {
            print("TOKEN: Authorization error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            self.authState = nil
        }
    })
```

The issue is that my access token retrieval code essentially hangs and never completes. It reaches the print statement `"REACHED"` but never comes out of this following portion of code:

```
appDelegate?.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: self, callback: {(_ authState: OIDAuthState?, _ error: Error?) -> Void in
        if (authState != nil) {
            print("TOKEN: Got authorization tokens. Access token: \(String(describing: authState?.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken))")
            self.newToken = authState?.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken

        }
        else {
            print("TOKEN: Authorization error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            self.authState = nil
        }
```

I do not either get a new token or get the `authorization error` print out.

I suspect it has something to do with my callbackURL. I don't think Swift knows where to "listen" to get my access token from. A callbackURL endpoint is relatively easy to set up server-side in node.js, for example, but how do I do this in Swift? Or is this even the real issue?

Comment: Hey, I'm also working on a Swift YouTube project. I'm having an issue using a refresh token to get a regular token with Alamofire, is there any chance you can help? The error = "unsupported_grant_type", and the description is "Invalid grant_type: ". Thanks! `let endpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"; let parameters = ["client_id" : client_id, "refresh_token" : refresh_token, "grant_type" : "refresh_token"]; Alamofire.request(endpoint, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)`

Comment: Sure. Post the question and the formatted source code of your controller as a question and tag me in the comments. It's hard to know what to answer since I only see a small snippet of your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989836/swift-alamofire-getting-token-from-refresh-token-request-error

Answer (score 0):

i have tired in my code like this way , you also need to check sometime encoding type **URLEncoding.httpBody** hope it may help , it helps me in using through oauth

```
 let headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]

    Alamofire.request("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={\(token)}", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
```